# Acronyms are not showing in the glossary

Tags: acronyms, glossary

I would like to make a list that shows both acronyms and a glossary. Currently only the glossary is showing and not the acronyms.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym, section]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries
  \newacronym{bpmn}{BPMN}{Business Process Modeling Notation}
  \newacronym{bpm}{BPM}{Business Process Model}

  \newglossaryentry{iot}
    {name= Internet of Thing (IoT), 
     description={Network of physical objects—“things”—that are embedded with sensors, software, and other technologies for the purpose of connecting and exchanging data with other devices and systems over the internet}}

\begin{document}
   %How I use the acronym in the text: 
      The \acrfull{bpmn} will be used to illustrate...

\chapter*{List of Terms and Acronyms}
\printnoidxglossary

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

What can I do to make this list also show the acronyms?

Answer (score 1):

`\printnoidxglossary` is equivalent to `\printnoidxglossary[type=main]`, which just prints the main glossary, the acronyms are created as a separate `type=acronym` glossary.

You can either use

```
\printnoidxglossaries
```

to print both at once, or call `\printnoidxglossary` multiple times with the different types

```
\printnoidxglossary
\printnoidxglossary[type=acronym]
```

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[acronym, section]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries
\newacronym{bpmn}{BPMN}{Business Process Modeling Notation}
\newacronym{bpm}{BPM}{Business Process Model}

\newglossaryentry{iot}
{name= Internet of Thing (IoT), 
description={Network of physical objects—“things”—that are embedded with sensors, software, and other technologies for the purpose of connecting and exchanging data with other devices and systems over the internet}}

\glsaddall

\begin{document}
\chapter*{List of Terms and Acronyms}
\printnoidxglossaries

\chapter*{Other List of Terms and Acronyms}
\printnoidxglossary
\printnoidxglossary[type=acronym]

\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled code showing both glossaries printed twice]